# Compress or shorten a long object? Vertices need to be closer together on one axis

Tags: vertices, transforms

Trying to fit clothing onto a model. The first problem I encounter is the fact that the legs are too long. What's a good way to shorten the legs?

[image]

Comment: You can select parts of the mesh around the bottom and use the proportional editing (press o) to move it around easily.

Comment: I would (as a start) put the 3D Cursor near the center of the groin area (select vertex on the symmetry axis and press Shift+S, and choose Cursor to Selected), then change the Transform Pivot Point (in the 3D Viewport Tool Settings) to 3D Cursor, and then scale the pants vertices below the cursor in the z-axis.